# Functions don't remain independent in C++?

Tags: c++, function

```
int evens(int x,int y);
int pdiv(int x,int y,int z);

void main(void)
{
  clrscr();
  cout<<"Enter the number x an y";
  int x,y;
  cin>>x>>y;
  evens(x,y);
  getch();
}

int evens(int x,int y)
{
  cout<<"Even Numbers between x and y are"<<endl;
  for (int z=x;z<y;z++)
  {
  if(z%2==0) cout<<z<<"  "<<pdiv(z,x,y);
  }
  return 0;
}

int pdiv(int x,int y,int z)
{
  cout<<"Positive divisors of the given number are"<<endl;
  for(int a=y;a<=z;a++)
  {
    if(x%a==0)
    cout<<a<<"  ";
  }
}
```

In the above program,whenever I use `pdiv(z,x,y)` in my `evens(x,y)` function the value of **x** and **y** in `evens(x,y)` starts to change. It doesn't happen when I don't call `pdiv()` in `evens()`.
I was taught that functions are independent and that they shouldn't alter the values of the other function,I have spent hours on this program and I can't figure out what wrong have I done.

Why my functions are not behaving as independent functions?

Comment: are you sure your code is correct? pdiv should actually return a number so that function should not work at all.

Comment: `pdiv()` is supposed to return an `int`, and `evens()` tries to print the `int` returned by `pdiv()`, but `pdiv()` doesn't actually return anything (i.e. the return value is undefined). Does this explain the odd behaviour you see?

Comment: ok. can u explain what the entire thing is supposed to do? i think that will be better.

Comment: There is a problem in the code. pdiv() is not returning any integer. Can you tell us what the code does exactly, that would help understanding the code.

Answer (score 2):

Functions in C++ are "independent", they cannot change values of the variables in another function unless you pass parameters by reference or do some hacks (which presumably you don't do). There are several things however that you might want to improve:

1. `pdiv` should return some `int` result
2. The way you call `pdiv(z,x,y)` is a bit misleading, because inside the function you will have variable `x` with the value of `z` from `evens()`. In C++ you don't pass parameters by name, the order is important. It would be much clearer if you don't change the meaning of the variables and call `pdiv(x,y,z)`.
3. in the `main()` you should assign some initial value for the variables `x` and `y`.
4. Why do you even think that the variables are changing?

Comment: By independent ,I meant that pdiv() dhouldn't alter the values of the function that is calling pdiv().But in my case whenever I call pdiv(z,x,y),in evens(x,y,z).The values of x and  y in evens(z,x,y) starts altering.I checked this this by taking cout<<x<<y; in evens(x,y,z).As long as pdiv(z,x,y) is not called the value of x and y remains unchanged (as is the user input to program).I knew that there is some problem with return but what I can't figure out is why the value of x and y in evens(x,y,z) are changing.
PS:I'm using Turbo C++ compiler.